Change default Wordpress Player
I'm running an Tube-Website based on WP-SCRIPT. I would love to change the default Wordpress Player to Ultimate Video Player WordPress (FWDesign).
I disabled the WPPlayer (plug-in specially developed for WP-Script websites) and uploaded the desired player, but Wordpress renders the basic player.
Even though the desired player is uploaded, Wordpress refuses to use it.
Any solution for this?
Tried to change the default player.
Tried other players (Prestoplayer) and had the same issue.
Tried some WP-Script settings but no result.
